# GAWK does not terminate after ENDFILE block with single file

Tags: awk

I have a gawk script below that reads a protein FASTA file and only prints out the records that don't have an X in their sequence and are within a certain range length. I wanted to modify the file in place so I had the script write to a temporary file and then rename it to the original file. The `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` constructs in gawk seemed convenient for this. However, for some reason, gawk does not exit after executing the code in the `ENDFILE` even if it is given a single file argument. It seems to jump back to another line of code and then just hang. Does anyone know what could cause this to happen? The weird part is that this doesn't happen for every FASTA file, only a few and I can't tell what is different between the ones that trigger the bug and the ones that don't

```
#! /bin/gawk -f

function trim(s) {
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "", s)
    return s
}

function printFasta(header, seq, outfile,    seq_line_max_chars) {
    print ">" header > outfile
    seq_line_max_chars = 80
    start = 1
    end = length(seq)
    while (start <= end) {
        print substr(seq, start, seq_line_max_chars) > outfile
        start += seq_line_max_chars
    }
}

BEGIN {
    min_prot_len = 400
}

BEGINFILE {
    tmp_out = FILENAME ".tmp"
}

/^>.+/ {
    headerStartIdx = index($0, ">") + 1
    header = trim(substr($0, headerStartIdx))

    getline
    sequence = ""
    while ($0 !~ /(^>.+)|(^[[:space:]]*$)/) {
        x_matched = match($0, "X")
        if (x_matched != 0) {
            next
        }

        gsub("*", "")
        sequence = sequence $0
        getline
    }

    if (length(sequence) >= min_prot_len) {
        printFasta(header, sequence, tmp_out)
    }
}

ENDFILE {
   print "move called"
   # system(("mv " tmp_out " " FILENAME)) 
}
```

I called the script with

```
$ ./filter_proteins.awk test.faa
```

When I run this, `move called` is printed and then it hangs. I tried stepping through with the debugger and I see that it reaches the `ENDFILE` block having processed all the lines in the input file, but when I type the `next` command, it jumps to the `getline` statement on line 44. After several iterations of `next` and `print $0` it seems that the program is stuck reading the last line of the input file till the end of time. Perhaps this is a bug?

I am using GAWK 5.1.0

**Edit**
A minimal input file.
https://github.com/CuriousTim/pastebin/blob/main/mb.34.faa
When I run the script with only a few sequences, it works, but when I use the whole file, it hangs. I wasn't sure how to make a minimal example without providing the whole file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also provide a minimal sample input file that we can test with.

Comment: When asking your next question - don't post links or images, post text in your question. If any sample input or output doesn't fit in  your question without a scroll bar then it's not a minimal example.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to post the link, but I couldn't find the minimum number of sequences that would reproduce the problem. I don't know why the script would work for a few sequence, but break for many.

Comment: Looking at your loop I'd expect you'd have the problem with every input file that doesn't have a blank as the last line since for a file that ends with a non-blank line that doesn't start with `>` it'll just keep looping re-testing $0 on every iteration and getline returning that same last line every time it fails because it's already reached the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll know for sure after you provide sample input to test with but my money's on the call to `getline` within the loop reaching the end of the file and so triggering the `ENDFILE` condition to be true but **you're still in the loop**.

Look:

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while (1) {
        print "about to execute getline"
        getline
        print "just executed getline:", $0
        if (++c == 5) {
            exit
        }
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    print "*** in ENDFILE ***"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
about to execute getline
just executed getline: bar
about to execute getline
*** in ENDFILE ***
just executed getline: bar
about to execute getline
just executed getline: bar
about to execute getline
just executed getline: bar
about to execute getline
just executed getline: bar
```

Calling `getline` in a loop is **not** how you want to write an awk script and what you have in your code is the wrong syntax to use when calling `getline` at any time - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: I was thinking about the problem and I suspected the `getline` might be the issue. Should I just move the regex in the while loop to its own block?

Comment: I don't know what your script is doing so I can't suggest how it should be written. You should accept this answer to the question you posted and post a new question with it's own [mcve] if you need help figuring out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way after trying to do it yourself by getting rid of the getlines as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my script to remove the `getline` in case anyone finds it useful.

```
#! /bin/gawk -f

function  printFasta(header, seq,    seq_line_max_chars) {
    print ">" header
    seq_line_max_chars = 80
    start = 1
    end = length(seq)
    while (start <= end) {
        print substr(seq, start, seq_line_max_chars)
        start += seq_line_max_chars
    }
}

BEGIN {
    FS = ">"
    min_prot_len = 400
    max_prot_len = 700
}

NF > 1 {
    if (sequence && 
        length(sequence) >= min_prot_len &&
        length(sequence) <= max_prot_len) {

        printFasta(header, sequence)
    }
}

{
    if (!header) {
        next
    } else {
         x_in_seq = match($0, "X")
         if (!x_in_seq) {
             gsub("*", "")
             sequence = sequence $0
         } else {
             header = ""
         }
    }
}

END {
    if (header) {
        printFasta(header, sequence)
    }
}
```